# Wireless not working on iMac G4

Tags: wireless, networking, mac

I have an iMac G4 running Ubuntu 12.4 PPC. When I try to connect to a wifi network, the computer doesn't seem to remember the SSID:

```
# iwconfig wlan0 essid <SSID>
# iwconfig
...
wlan0    IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:<SSID>
         Mode:Managed Frequency:2.427 GHz Access Point: Not-Associated
         ...
```

A few minutes later...

```
# iwconfig
...
wlan0    IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:off/any
         Mode:Managed Frequency:2.427 GHz Access Point: Not-Associated
         ...
```

I can provide other logs/output as needed.

Comment: What method of authentication does your access point use?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kX9QLXUp

Comment: cc @WildMan in case you didn't get it. (btw that's one *awesome* script!)

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

This will tell you what is in a file called interfaces. You should see:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I already know that file is empty according to the information you posted. Please add those two lines and nothing else. Save, close gedit and reboot. If you have another text editor instead of gedit you will use it in the command above in place of gedit.

If you did not manually setup interfaces run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

if you want to have reslovconfig configured manually then you will want to remove network manager.

Comment: @Seth thanks for letting me know about the file being posted, about half the time I do not receive notification and this time I did not as well. Thanks for your kind comments on the script there were some great people working on it with me that made it possible.